# How to remove X-Frame-Options from the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, x-frame-options

I have a problem with X-Frame-Options http header.

I use MVC 5, so SAMEORIGIN option is automatically added in Headers for Http Responses.

I still want to use default option and I don't want to use below line in  Application_Start:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

I would like to remove X-Frame-Options header in some particular action on controller level with code like that:

```
base.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

However, it doesn't work.

Do you know how can I remove it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After investigating the problem, I noticed that it is possible to create an ActionFilter which overrides OnResultExecuted method, where I can remove that http header:

```
public class AllowIframeFromUriAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //...
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

It works so I'd like to share the solution.